# Postmaster SPF FAILing/Email headers show PASS

Tags: email, gmail, dkim, dmarc

I'm using a domain (say xyz.com) to send marketing mails. We've done SPF/DKIM/DMARC authentication and we see the same in the email body (show original option in gmail)- SPF PASS DKIM PASS but the same domain in postmaster shows 100% DKIM, 0% DMARC, 0% SPF in authentication?

Any idea what is happening here? Also how important is RDNS for gmail spam filters?

Answer (score 2):

rDNS is very important to a lot of domains, definitely set that up if you haven't yet.

Based on what you're describing it doesn't sound right if you're mailing the same way from two different @, the authentication should be set the same. Unless you have some sort of routing rule.

You should send an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` with both emails and compare the results. It might shed some light on what's going on. You can read about all the [email tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/).